# how to run nunit tests ordered by categories in same namespace, without mix tests?

Tags: testing, nunit, sql-order-by, categories

My question is as follows:

I have a quantity if test cases in the same namespace, these test cases are categorized By A and B categories, I need to run first category A and then Category B.

The problem is, when i select categories (at nunit gui), the tool run the test in the order they appear, not by category as i'm expecting.

For example, I have the test cases:

- WhenUserTriesToAddLineItemGroup [Cateogry B]
- WhenUserTriesToCreateTopic  [Cateogry A]
- WhenUserTriesToCreateAreas  [Cateogry A]

I need to run first: 
   WhenUserTriesToCreateTopic and WhenUserTriesToCreateAreas
and second: 
   WhenUserTriesToAddLineItemGroup

but they are running in the order as they are in the list. Please, how can i do to run the tests in the way I need?

Thanks!!

Comment: Unit tests should be isolated from each other so that they can be run in any order or one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

NUnit is built on the notion that any single test is completely autonomous. If you have things that need to be done before the test can be run, they might be put in a `SetUp` method, and if your test has any side-effects you might have a `TearDown` method to undo those side-effects, but otherwise it assumes that any single test can be run at any time, and that test order does not matter. This has several advantages for developers, since you can run any set of your tests without worrying about their prerequisites, and the pass/fail condition of one test does not depend on the pass/fail condition of a different test.

I would suggest that you reconsider why your tests have these restrictions in the first place, and try to rewrite them so that they test more isolated pieces of functionality, and do not have a prerequisite state of your system. In principle you could combine these tests into a single test, so that you can handle the dependencies, but that's not usually a great solution, since it will often lead to very large tests (whereas unit tests are usually testing a very small condition or piece of functionality). It would be better to take a look at what conditions you need to test, and write each test from the ground up to test just that condition, without assuming that your system is in any state or that any other tests have already been run.

Without more specifics about what you are trying to test it's hard to give a concrete suggestion for how to improve your system, but in general you will get the most out of unit testing if each test is completely autonomous.